# Svn/Git for two man drupal project?

Tags: svn, git, drupal, cvs, hgsubversion

What is the best method to work with remote person on drupal development? We are only two people so is cvs /svn is overkill? Is there an online solution for things?

Comment: I think what you're trying to say is Version control overkill, rather than svn/cvs/git.

Comment: Version control is so lightweight and so useful, that it isn't overkill even for a one-man project. I use Git for everything now, even important documents.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Always, *Always* use source control.

## NO EXCEPTIONS.

#### NO EXCUSES

- Are there any Good excuses no not use Source/Version control? [**No,** not even one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/132520/good-excuses-not-to-use-version-control)

Even when there is only 1 person working on a project, the utility source control brings much greatly outweighs the costs of using it.

When there is 2 people working on a project, not using source control is tantamount to suicide, because what else will you do when another person accidentally overwrites your file containing the changes you just spent hours working on?

Some source control is easier to set up. I myself, love git, because

```
cd project
git init
```

and we're done.

You can work out the rest of the distribution stuff at a latter point, and not have the risk of not being able to go back in time and see what you changed.

Answer (score 0):

I would advice to use some sort of version control even if you are working alone on a project. Of course one of the features of many version control solutions is merging, but the fact that you have a history of all changes that are made is the most powerful feature if you asked me.

So is CVS/SVN overkill I dont believe it will be unless you are going to play around and not building something concrete. There are many online solutions like github and google code but the costs of this depend on you project open source or not.

Answer (score 0):

I use version control for everything I develop, even if it's just a 10-line script. (Well, I don't use it for stack overflow answer examples.)  Sometimes I run one local VCS during initial development and then switch to a project VCS.

It's completely appropriate for a 2-person project, in fact, it's almost uncivilized to try and get along without it.  It will save you time and prepare you for future collaborative work.

There are lots of online providers of svn repositories and some well-known git services too,

Avoid CVS. It was a huge step forward 20 years ago and it ruled the VCS landscape for a while, but you shouldn't touch it today for a new project.

Comment: ok so what your recommend? what is the "10 lines of code" ? and also, is it good to implemnet it with eclipse pdt?

Answer (score 0):

To answer the actual question and give a tip, our source control method with Drupal is to add the `/yoursite/sites/` into source control. That way all modules and theme stuff are saved into revision control, not the Drupal core which you aren't ment to touch anyway.

Setting ignores to settings.php and files folders is a good idea as well, latter depending on if there will be a lot of files or not (it's arguable if user uploaded images etc. should be source controlled, we don't think they should be).